# i2cdetect shows all possible adresses

Tags: i2c, rip

I have accidentally connected (SDA, SCL) with (5v, GND) (the two pins next to them), after doing so the raspberry pi has been overheating just by connecting it with power source (with no pins connected), and using i2cdetect shows all possible adresses

Comment: likely your Pi is dead or dying.

Comment: i2cdetect showing all addresses is a symptom of the SDA GPIO being permanently connected to ground, i.e. bust.  The Pi overheating is a symptom of the GPIO circuitry having been exposed to 5V at currents the internal protection circuitry can't handle (anything more than half a milliamp or so) .  The damage spreads through the circuitry until the Pi completely dies.

Comment: Ah ha, someone beat me to the application of the [tag:rip] tag! 8-)

Comment: @joan You should turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: The good news is the Rpi 3 - you now have a great opportunity to pick one up for very little cash outlay.

Answer (score 4):

i2cdetect showing all addresses is a symptom of the SDA GPIO being permanently connected to ground, i.e. bust.

The Pi overheating is a symptom of the GPIO circuitry having been exposed to 5V at currents the internal protection circuitry can't handle (anything more than half a milliamp or so). The damage spreads through the circuitry until the Pi completely dies.